# Integer programming example clarification

Tags: integer-programming, big-m

There is an explanation in my book for an integer programming example, which goes like this:

A company is considering manufacturing three types of autos: compact, midsize, and large. The resources required, and the profits yielded, by each type of car are shown in the table. \begin{array}{c|ccc|c}&&\underline{\text{Car Type}}&&\text{Available}\\\text{Resource}&\text{Compact}&\text{Midsize}&\text{Large}&\text{Resources}\\\hline \text{Steel Required}&1.5\,\,\text{tons}&3 \,\,\text{tons}&5 \,\,\text{tons}&6000\,\, \text{tons}\\\text{Labour Required}&30\,\, \text{hrs}&25 \,\,\text{hrs}&40\,\, \text{hrs}&60000 \,\,\text{hrs}\\\hline \text{Profit}\,\, ({\it£})&2000&3000&4000&\\\hline\end{array} For the production of a type of car to be economically feasible, at least $1000$ cars of that type must be produced.
Formulate an IP to maximize the profit.

**Solution:**

Let $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ be the number of compact, midsize and large cars produced respectively.

*Resource Constraints:*
\begin{align}1.5x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3&\leq 6000 \ \ \text{(Steel resource)}\\30x_1 + 25x_2 + 40x_3 &\leq 60000 \ \ \text{(Labour resource)}\end{align} If we decide to produce any cars of a given type, then it must be at least $1000$ cars of that type. \begin{align}\text{Constraint 3}:x_1 \le 0 \ \ &\text{or} \ \ x_1\ge 1000\\\text{Constraint 4}:x_2 \le 0 \ \ &\text{or} \ \ x_2\ge 1000\\\text{Constraint 5}:x_3 \le 0 \ \ &\text{or} \ \ x_3\ge 1000.\end{align}

> For Constraint $3$, $x_1 \le 0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ x_1\ge 1000$ so \begin{align}\text{Either}&\quad x_1\le0\color{maroon}{+My_1}\\\text{or}&\quad-x_1\le-1000\color{maroon}{+M(1-y_1)}\\&\quad y_1=0\ \ \text{or}\ \ 1\end{align} When $y_1=0$, \begin{align}x_1&\le0\\-x_1&\le-1000+M\end{align} and when $y_1=1$, \begin{align}x_1&\le M\\-x_1&\le-1000.\end{align} The constant $M$ should not restrict the values of decision variables, so \begin{align}1.5x_1+3x_2+5x_3&\le6000\\30x_1+25x_2+40x_3&\le60000.\end{align} For $x_1$, $M\ge2000$. For $x_2$, $M\ge2000$. For $x_3$, $M\ge1200$.

I don't understand why $M_1, M_2, M_3$ are equal or bigger than $2000$, $2000$ and $1200$ respectively. From where have these numbers been deduced? I'm confused.

Comment: It's the upper bound for each variable given the two constraints.

Comment: @Stradivari okay but why exactly those numbers? just random numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose large numbers for your $M$s (big-M) (that's why they are called that), but you also want to make sure they are not very large. See the discussions [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-is-it-important-to-choose-big-m-carefully-and-what-are-the-consequences-of-d) and [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/126/the-effect-of-choosing-big-m-properly) for the reasons.

In your example, your big-Ms just need to be bigger than the upper bound of the values that the variables can take (as @Stradivari mentioned). So, for each of $x_1, x_2, x_3$, take the $\min$ of values they can get from the resource (steel and labor) constraints and you get your big-Ms.

For example for $x_1$:
$$\min\left(\frac{6000}{1.5}, \frac{60000}{30}\right)=2000 $$

Do the same for $x_2$ and $x_3$ and you get $2000$ and $1200$, respectively.

Comment: Okay! thanks for clarifying!!